# Display UIMenuController in UIBarButton Click

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to display a UIMenuController in a Toolbar button. I have the code below but I am unsure as to what should be in the "SetTargetRect" method.

What should I put in the SetTargetRect method to display the Menu?

Is there anything else that is missing from this code?

```
ToolbarItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { 
new UIBarButtonItem ("Sort", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (sender, e) => {
    var menu = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;
    menu.MenuItems = new UIMenuItem[] {
        new UIMenuItem ("Current", new Selector ("SortRaceEntrants")),
        new UIMenuItem ("Movers", new Selector ("SortRaceEntrants")),
        new UIMenuItem ("Opening", new Selector ("SortRaceEntrants")),
        new UIMenuItem ("Number", new Selector ("SortRaceEntrants"))
    };
    //menu.SetTargetRect ();
    menu.SetMenuVisible (true, true);
}),
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html), the target rect defines the area that you want to display the menu relative to - iOS will either show the menu above or below the area defined by TargetRect.

> When you make this menu visible, UIMenuController positions it
>   relative to a target rectangle on the screen; this rectangle usually
>   defines a selection. The menu appears above the target rectangle or,
>   if there is not enough space for it, below it. The menu’s pointer is
>   placed at the center of the top or bottom of the target rectangle, as
>   appropriate. Be sure to set the tracking rectangle before you make the
>   menu visible. You are also responsible for detecting, tracking, and
>   displaying selections.

and

> This target rectangle (targetRect) is usually the bounding rectangle
>   of a selection. UIMenuController positions the editing menu above this
>   rectangle; if there is not enough space for the menu there, it
>   positions it below the rectangle. The menu’s pointer is placed at the
>   center of the top or bottom of the target rectangle as appropriate.
>   Note that if you make the width or height of the target rectangle
>   zero, UIMenuController treats the target area as a line or point for
>   positioning (for example, an insertion caret or a single point).
>
> Once it is set, the target rectangle does not track the view; if the
>   view moves (such as would happen in a scroll view), you must update
>   the target rectangle accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your answer. That clarifies things for me. So I need to set the target rectangle to that of the UIBarButtonItem. How might I go about getting/creating the rectangle for the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: try using the Frame of the button

Comment: Hi Jason. I am not 100% sure how to get the Frame of the button. I have tried NavigationController.Toolbar.Subviews[1].Frame. But still no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do it for a UIBarButtonItem.  For purposes of testing, you might want to pick an arbitrary point right in the middle of your view and use that as the frame.  If that works, then you can adjust the position of the frame to be where you want it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem inherits from UIBarItem and NSObject, so finding a frame for them is not easy if not impossible.  UINavigationBar inherits from UIView and thus is a view (go figure) and has a frame, etc.

What I do is point to a rect inside that view where the UIBarButtonItem should be.

For example:

```
[myMenu setTargetRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 25) 
               inView:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
```

This will make the UIMenuController 'point' at the leftBarButtonItem.
The same technique can be used for the toolbar.

In your case something like:

```
[menu setTargetRect:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)
             inView:self.navigationController.toolBar];
```

would point to the center of the toolBar and thus the center button in the toolBar

Comment: The nice thing about this is that if you have a scrollView there is no need to update the targetRect when the scrollView moves.